# Fancybox not firing - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I feel really dumb for not being able to see this but for some reason I can't even get the basic portion of `fancybox` to work on my website.

I would think it'd be a conflict but I stripped the other scripts out of it and it still wouldn't fire.I've double checked to make sure I only have `jquery` loading once because I've been guilty of that before so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
 
The site is http://southernjewlz.com and at the very bottom left under the footer is a link that says "test" that should be linked up to display the logo in a popup.

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function : $(".fancybox").fancybox();` and there are other 5 JS errors.

Comment: I stripped out the unnecessary optional scripts and took off the versions and I've still got 2 javascript errors but I don't understand what is causing them. If I toggle for more details it looks like it's seeing an error in the actual fancybox script and the jquery-latest script. Am I reading that right?

Comment: Change all the instance of `$` to `jQuery` in the code you are using to instantiate Fancybox and see if that helps.

Comment: that doesn't seem to have changed anything. If I used a fancybox plugin it works fine so I feel it has to be something that I'm putting in wrong.